# jquery element has same class of another element with two class

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a menu like this into my website:

```
<div class="menu">
    <p align="left" id="home" class="titolo_menu">home</p>
    <p align="left" id="azienda" class="titolo_menu azienda"><br>azienda</p>
    <p align="left" id="staff" class="titolo_sotto_menu azienda">staff</p>
    <p align="left" id="risorseumane" class="titolo_sotto_menu azienda">risorse umane</p>
    <p align="left" id="servizi" class="titolo_menu servizi"><br>servizi</p>
    <p align="left" id="servizioclienti" class="titolo_sotto_menu servizi">servizio clienti</p>
    <p align="left" id="prodotti" class="titolo_menu prodotti"><br>prodotti</p>
    <p align="left" id="web" class="titolo_sotto_menu prodotti">web</p>
</div>
```

I want to check when I click an element if has a class of the old page.
I store the id of old page in my php session and retrieve after in javascript. 
Example my old page id is: "azienda" (is the of the `p` of my menu).
I search into my menu the element that have the id "azienda" and I want to compair with the element that I have click now for example staff.
I want to compaire if my p with id"staff" contain a part of class, in this case "azienda", with old p clicked. In this case match.
The problem is that I have two classes into my p, if there was only one isn't a problem but with two I want to compair only the second class.

```
 $('.titolo_sotto_menu').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');//staff
        var class=$(this).attr('class');
        var page=id;

        old_page=actual_page;//azienda
        actual_page=page;

        var class_old = $('#'+old_page).attr('class');

        if (class == class_old){
            //do something
        }   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function element.hasClass('classname') of jQuery.

```
var classes[] = class.split(' ');
for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
if ($('#'+old_page).hasClass(classes[i])){
            //do something
        }
}
```

Comment: No because the class is dunamic and in this case if I take the first element and its class I have two class into the element and I want to search only one of that class

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you will only be needing to check the second class, then just extract the second class from the element.

```
var secondClass = $('#idOfElement').attr('class').split(' ')[1]
```

Further, you may want to add a check to see if there are two classes:

```
var secondClass = $('#idOfElement').attr('class').split(' ').length > 1 
? $('#idOfElement').attr('class').split(' ')[1] 
: $('#idOfElement').attr('class');
```

Answer (score -1):

[$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) may be of some help. Let me know :)